# Java Tic Tac Toe with ImageIcons - Suggestions for Improvement

Tags: java, swing

I programmed Tic Tac Toe in Java with ImageIcons (sun.png, devil.png).

Everything works well, but the question is if there is a better way to filter out who's turn it is. In the moment I use a variable `String` player and the letters `O` and `X`.

But I ask myself if there is a way to ask something like `if (count %2 == 0) {player = sun}` because I want to get away from `X`'s and `O`'s because of the `ImageIcon`s (the user don't know if he is `X` or `O`). I hope you understand what I mean and it's not too confusing. Thank you very much for your efforts and answers! I am thankful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do instead is set your `player` variable to be a `boolean`. In this case, I would instantiate this as something similar to:

```
private boolean is_player_one = true;
```

To check whose turn it is, you can use a simple `if/else`:

```
if (is_player_one) {
    // Player one's turn
} else {
    // Player two's turn
}
```

Then, at the end of either player's turn, you simply invert the boolean to switch players:

```
is_player_one = !is_player_one;
```

EDIT:

Only one boolean variable is needed. I will rename the variable to `is_player_sun` to make this more clear for your situation. If the value of `is_player_sun` is `true`, then it is player sun's turn. If `is_player_sun` has a value of `false`, then it is player devil's turn. So the final `if/else` case, including an update of turns, should look similar to:

```
if (is_player_sun) {
    // Player sun's turn
} else {
    // Player devil's turn
}
is_player_sun = !is_player_sun;
```

Note that you don't need a variable `is_player_devil` because player devil's turn is when `is_player_sun` is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand you right.. First I initialize is_player_devil , is_player_sun and in the beginning is false or isn't it?:

```
  private boolean is_player_devil = false;
        private boolean is_player_sun = false;
```

And in the part of Who's turn is it i can simply type is_player_sun = true;

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        count++;

        // Who's turn is it
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            //player = "O";
            is_player_sun = true;

        } else {
            //player = "X";
            is_player_devil = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have an ImageIcon that represents the current player. In your `PlayField` class:

```
private ImageIcon currentPlayer;

...

public Playfield() {
  currentPlayer = devil;

...

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
  JButton pressedButton = (JButton) a.getSource();
  pressedButton.setIcon(currentPlayer);
  pressedButton.setDisabledIcon(currentPlayer);
  pressedButton.setEnabled(false);

  currentPlayer = currentPlayer.equals(devil) ? sun : devil;
```